# How to exclude unmatched playbook when filtering by hosts and tags

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

When I run the following command:

```
ansible-playbook <mybook.yml> -l <myhost> -t <mytag> -D -C --list-hosts --list-tasks
```

I received a full list of plays with empty matches (either it does match the host or the task):

```
  play #N (xxx): Task name TAGS: []
    pattern: ['xxx']
    hosts (0):
    tasks:
```

Is there a way to tell ansible just to give me the matched play?

Comment: `ansible-doc -t callback --list` will interest you; I can't link to the list online because they killed it when they "collection-ed" everything

Comment: @mdaniel: were you looking for [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)?